# Classification of numbers on the base of binary representation

Tags: number-theory, binary

The problem is the following. I would like to find a simple algorithm or principle of classification of numbers regarding their presentation in binary form.

Let's consider an example. The numbers by 4-digit binary numbers are following:

$0000_2=0$

$0001_2=1$

$0010_2=2$

$\vdots $

$1111_2=15$

I need to divide the set {0,1,...,15} into subsets, each member of which can be presented by certain numbers of binary ones in binary representation.

I.e.

$C_0=\{0\}$   ($0$ binary ones)

$C_1=\{1, 2, 4, 8\}$   (1 binary one: $0001_2$, $0010_2$, $0100_2$, $1000_2$)

$C_2= \{3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12\}$ (2 binary ones)

$\vdots $

$C_5=\{ 15 \}$

Does there exist a result from the number theory allowing to reveal these subsets without transition to binary representation?

Comment: You could calculate $f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{3}\left[\lfloor(n/2^i)\rfloor\text{ mod  }2\right]$. Then $f(n)=f(m)$ if and only if $n, m$ have an equal number of $1$'s

Answer (score 2):

The number of ones in the binary representation of $n$ is the greatest integer $r$ such that $2^r$ divides
$$\binom{2n}n$$

See https://oeis.org/A000120

It is not too hard (but not too simple, either) to prove this by induction.

Comment: Indeed?
For $n=3$: $C_6^3=20$, but 3 is presented by $2$ binary ones: 3 = $11_2$.

Comment: and $r=2$ is the largest integer such that $2^r$ divides $20$.

Comment: I see, but it is desirable to have more simple methods of calculation. Nevertheless, I appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this on a computer, it seems kind of strange to me that you want to bypass the binary representation of the numbers.

But I'll try. Another user already mentioned [Sloane's A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120), which includes this recurrence relation: $a(0) = 0, a(2n) = a(n), a(2n + 1) = a(n) + 1$. If your subset starts on $0$ or a power of $2$ and runs consecutively through a number of the form $2^k -1$, it might be practical to run through the recurrence relation for those numbers and then sort them according to the results.

Also notice the following facts, some more obvious than others:

- Only $0$ has a binary weight of $0$.
- The numbers with a binary weight of $1$ are the powers of $2$ (thus $1, 2, 4, 8$).
- All numbers of the form $3 \times 2^k$, $5 \times 2^k$ or $9 \times 2^k$ for $k \geq 0$ have a binary weight of $2$ ($3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12$; there are other numbers with this same weight, but no more in the range $0$ to $15$).
- The primes $7$, $11$, $13$ have a binary weight of $3$. Also $14 = 7 \times 2$.
- $15$ has a binary weight of $4$.

The main take-away from this is that if have one number with a certain binary weight, you can find infinitely many more numbers with that same binary weight by the simple action of multiplying by powers of $2$. But to find *all* numbers with that binary weight within a given finite range, you have to find all "primitive" combinations of the necessary number of on bits with the appropriate number of off bits inserted (by "primitive" here I mean odd).